# Only the first data display from my database but other shows but not on a table

Tags: php, cakephp

Please kindly look into my code and help me fix the errors in my code. only my first data displays on the table  on my view page but the other data displays on  the view page not on the table.

my image name and the image itself successfully inserted in my database and my image directory which i name "upload" but the image wont display on my view page.

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
// Retrieve data from database 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>firstname</th>
<th>lastname</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>nationality</th>
<th>accountnumber</th>
<th>accounttype</th>
<th>balance</th>
<th>passport</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>passport</th>
<th>update</th>
<th>delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nationality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['account'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['accounttype'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><h1><img src=\"upload/\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[id]</h1></td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";``
 echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">update</a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">delete</a></td>";
echo "</table>";

// close while loop 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a quick view, I see you are closing the table inside the while loop. You should change it for a

```
</tr>
```

and remember using the thead and tbody tags.
Close tbody and table after ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be outside your while loop.

```
echo "</table>";
```

And

```
<img src=\"upload/\"
```

Is only pointing to the upload directory, you aren't specifying an actual image. Try something like:

```
echo "<td><h1><img src=\"upload/$row['image']\" height=35 width=35  /> $row['id']</h1></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. the table issue worked but the image code didnt work but i used it like this and it worked. thanks and God bless. echo "<td><h1><img src=\"upload/$row[photo]\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[id]</h1></td>";

Comment: I didn't know the column name because you never specified it, so I just guessed. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Moving  the table closing tab out side the while loop will solve the first issue.

Change the code as follows to solve the image problem.

```
echo '<td><img src="upload/'.$row['your image name'].'" height=35 width=35 ></td>';
```

Your code should be as follows.

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
// Retrieve data from database 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>firstname</th>
<th>lastname</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>nationality</th>
<th>accountnumber</th>
<th>accounttype</th>
<th>balance</th>
<th>passport</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>passport</th>
<th>update</th>
<th>delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nationality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['account'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['accounttype'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><img src="upload/'.$row['your image name'].'" height=35 width=35 ></td>';  
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";``
  echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">update</a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">delete</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";

// close while loop 
}
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am having a little  difficulty in displaying my id info on my update page.  i have two entries 6 and 7 if i click update on id 6 , it will show on my update page but if i click update on id 7, on the address bar, it will indicate that the id =7 but it will still show id 6 infos.

here is my display code that display data on my update page

```
 <?ph
 include ('config.php');  
 // Retrieve data from database 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>
```

secondly if i change data my update page, the change wont reflect on my view page.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
$accountnumber=$_POST['account'];
$accounttype=$_POST['accounttype'];
$balance=$_POST['balance'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', address='$address', nationality='$nationality',accountnumber='$account',accounttype='$accounttype',balance='$balance',username='$username',password='$password'
WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

header ("Location: details.php");

?>
```